# Including 401(k) contributions on Canadian tax return

Tags: income-tax, canada, 401k, rrsp, canada-revenue-agency

I am a Canadian resident who made US income, and contributed to a 401k. I know I must include my 401k contributions on my foreign income, but what about my employer's contributions?

Also, what are the ways that I can get these amounts deducted from my Canadian income tax? I have plenty of RRSP contributions left to make.

Answer (score 1):

Canadian residents working in the US and contributing to a 401(k) do need to include their own 401(k) contributions in their reported income. However, since 2009 they can deduct those contributions on line 209(?). A treaty revison made this possible.

Comment: Welcome to [Money.SE].  Your answer addresses the half of the question about employee contributions; can you also address the issue of employer contributions?